# Create a wiggle effect for a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-effects

So what I want to happen is that when viewing the Span the text is normal but as you scroll down it starts moving until it looks like such:

Before the effect:
[image: Before the effect]

While the effect occurs:
[image: While the effect occurs]

The header is represented by spans for each letter. In the initial state, the top pixel value for each is 0. But the idea as mentioned is that that changes alongside the scroll value.

I wanted to keep track of the scroll position through JS and jQuery and then change the pixel value as needed. But that's what I have been having trouble with. Also making it smooth has been another issue.

Comment: adding some code to show what you've done so far would be helpful

Comment: @ControlAltDel how can you track scroll position with css?

Comment: @jmona789 sorry about that the code I had currently was using a completely different method and It didn't work well so I scrapped it. And I didn't really have the best idea how to make this myself so thats why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will be the core of your JS functionality:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  var scrl = window.scrollY

  // Changing the position of elements that we want to go up
  document.querySelectorAll('.up').forEach(function(el){
    el.style.top = - scrl/30 +'px';
  });

  // Changing the position of elements that we want to go down
  document.querySelectorAll('.down').forEach(function(el){
    el.style.top = scrl/30 +'px';
  });
});
```

We're basically listening in on the **scroll event**, checking how much has the user scrolled and then act upon it by offsetting our spans *(which i've classed as up & down)*

### [JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/jabigov/16/edit?html,js,output)

> Something you can improve on yourself would be making sure that the letters wont go off the page when the user scrolls a lot.
>   You can do this with simple math calculation, taking in consideration the window's total height and using the current `scrollY` as a multiplier.

*- As RokoC has pointed out there is room for performance improvements.
Implement some debouncing or other kinds of limiters*

Comment: This is a performance killer and should be improved... On every scroll-tick query the whole DOM for two different class elements is not good.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan that's true but performance and other improvements could be implemented by Shihab. This is just a basis.

Comment: Maybe make up and down animations in css and by some interval loop in js add and remove classes to certain elements.

Comment: @Mihailo thanks so much. This makes a lot sense. And I'll keep trying to improve the performance as well as add a limiter.

Comment: @ShihabUddin glad you found it useful. By the way clabe's answer is pretty interesting as well.

Comment: @Mihailo Does the position need to be fixed? Right now it acts almost like a nav bar. Like it goes down the page along with he scroll. I've been trying different ways to restrict it but that's the functionality of fixed.

Comment: It should work with position relative as well. Depends how you want it to behave.

Answer (score 2):

Use the mathematical functions [*sine* and *cosine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions), for characters at even and odd indices respectively, as the graphs of the functions move up and down like waves. This will create a smooth effect:

[image: Sine and cosine graphs]

`cos(x) == 1 - sin(x)`, so in a sense, each character will be the "opposite" of the next one to create that scattered look:

```js
function makeContainerWiggleOnScroll(container, speed = 0.01, distance = 4) {
  let wiggle = function() {
    // y-axis scroll value
    var y = window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop;
    // make div pseudo-(position:fixed), because setting the position to fixed makes the letters overlap
    container.style.marginTop = y + 'px';
    for (var i = 0; i < container.children.length; i++) {
      var span = container.children[i];
      // margin-top = { amplitude of the sine/cosine function (to make it always positive) } + { the sine/cosine function (to make it move up and down }
      // cos(x) = 1 - sin(x)
      var trigFunc = i % 2 ? Math.cos : Math.sin;
      span.style.marginTop = distance + distance * trigFunc(speed * y)/2 + 'px';
    }

  };
  window.addEventListener('scroll', wiggle);
  wiggle(); // init
}

makeContainerWiggleOnScroll(document.querySelector('h2'));
```

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <span>H</span><span>e</span><span>a</span><span>d</span><span>e</span><span>r</span>
</h2>
```

**Important styling note:** *the spans' `display` must be set to `inline-block`, so that `margin-top` works*.